# How to configure schema for R2DBC PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data, r2dbc

I try to use Spring Data R2DBC with postgres.

I know some configuration for url, username, password.

```
spring.r2dbc.url
spring.r2dbc.username
spring.r2dbc.password
```

Is there something for the schema?
Any list of setting available?

Answer (score 12):

Schema is Postgres-specific and can be configured through the R2DBC Connection URL:

```
r2dbc:postgresql://<server>:<port>/<database>?schema=<yourSchema>
```

See also:

- [Documentation](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-postgresql#usage)

Answer (score 12):

More pretty way to pass schema in properties:
in **yaml** format:

```
spring:
  r2dbc:
    properties:
      schema: <yourSchema>
```

or **properties** format:

```
spring.r2dbc.properties.schema: <yourSchema>
```